# WooCommerce - always calculate shipping on update_order_review

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to always fire off the `calculate_shipping` method when `update_order_review` is called on the checkout page.

I cannot find the logic where it decides whether or not to call calculate shipping. I can confirm that unless I change the shipping address or similar it does not fire off the `calculate_shipping` method.

I've been trying to follow the code, both from `calculate_shipping` up and `update_order_review` down but I cannot make heads or tails of it.

**Tried**

There is a `set_calculated_shipping` on the customer class method right before `calculate_totals` method is called on the cart class in class-wc-ajax.php I thought might be related. I tried changing the value, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.